# Html Helper to Tag Helper Conversion

Tags: asp.net-core

Has anyone discovered some software to "automatically" convert ASP.NET Standard Html Helpers to ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers?  I'd like to update a website that I have, and I have used the Microsoft converter to migrate it from .NET standard to .NET Core, but there are hundreds of web pages that I would like to update, but the converter does not touch.  I'm wondering if someone else smarter than I has written an application to do this conversion already?

[Telerik has one posted on GitHub](https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter), but it is only for their products.  I would like something for vanilla Html Helpers.

Example:

From: `@Html.Label(Global.SerialNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })`

To: `<label class="control-label col-md-2">@Global.SerialNo</label>`